# How do you set the Swype keyboard to delete the entire word when the delete button is held down?

Tags: swype

Older version did this but now it only happens to the first word. "If I have a sentence like this" and wanted to delete all the way to "If I" I could have held down the delete key and after a second it would start deleting word by word.

Comment: I have seen my friend swiping left over the keyboard to delete the words.

Comment: @roxan can you elaborate "left over the keyboard"?

Comment: Just swipe your fingers from right to left over the home rows of your keyboard.

Comment: What is "home row"? Can you post an example of screen shot or video?

Comment: Slide your finger over ";lkjhgfdsa" keys on the swype keyboard.

Comment: @roxan that doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: I'm sorry then. My friend used to do it in that way. I confirmed with him, he says just swype from left to right over the keyboard, over the home rows, (home rows = key rows with asdf in it)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this feature was disabled in the latest version of Swype:  http://forum.swype.com/archive/index.php/t-6439.html

> phargarten
> 06-22-2012, 11:16 AM
> Hey Swypers,
>
> We've changed the delete behavior a bit -- and while it took me a day to get used to it, I have to say it has sped up my Swyping a bit. So here's a couple changes we've made to the deletion behavior:
>
> 1. Pressing delete after Swyping a word will delete the entire word. We find that Swype is rarely off by a little. If we don't guess the word you want, you probably want to delete the whole word and Swype again, rather than deleting a few characters. So delete after a Swyped word will delete the entire word.
> 2. For this reason, the long press "Delete word back" function has been removed.
>
> Remember, you can always press the Swype key to highlight the word next to the cursor. Swype another word to replace the highlighted text.
>
> Cheers and Happy Swyping!
>
> Peter@SwypeSupport